# Wrapping a non IO bound long running synchronous API in an async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, interop

I have a c++ DLL that sends data to a USB device and waits for a reply (could be up to 10 seconds), there is no build in callback for this DLL. If I call this from my UI thread it locks the UI obviously.

I have currently written an async wrapper for this C++ library in C# that wraps the dll call eg

```
public async Task<USBResult> GetData(int command){

     //The real function has C#/C++ interop code to marshal the memory and free it.
     USBResult result;

     //This function most likely calls Thread.Sleep whilst it waits for a callback internally. 
     //I know it uses FTDIx.dll to do the USB calls.
     await Task.Run(() result = LongRunningDllCallWithNoCallback(command));

     return result;
}
```

I've read that async over sync is not recommended however I see no other way to achieve this functionality in my case. I cannot modify the c++ dll and the developer would not either as it conforms to an SAE standard that was written 15 years ago and hence would break other applications if changed.

Is this bad practice? If so what would be the preferred way to create an async function over this long running synchronous dll call?

Answer (score 2):

> I've read that async over sync is not recommended however I see no other way to achieve this functionality in my case.

Correct, it's not recommended.

In your case - where you have something that cannot be made asynchronous - you should expose a synchronous API, e.g.:

```
public USBResult GetData(int command) {
  // C#/C++ interop code to marshal the memory and free it.
  USBResult result;
  result = LongRunningDllCallWithNoCallback(command);
  return result;
}
```

And then when the time is right to call it from the UI, then *invoke* it using `await Task.Run`, as such:

```
var response = await Task.Run(() => GetData(command));
```

For more information about the reasoning behind this, see my blog post [`Task.Run` in the implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Comment: I actually did what you suggested after reading it was not recommended. Your blog explains it well, thanks.